# Tabbed Activity=>Binary XML file line : Error inflating class null

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-tabbed-activity

But another tabbed activity is running flawlessly which has similar code to this activity.
Even changed layout files but same error message is displayed.

```
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;  


   public class Fees1due extends Fragment {   
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fees1due, container, false);//////Error pointing here.///


return rootView;
}
}
```

**Layout:fees1due**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="com.example.arjun.scol.Fees.FeesMain$PlaceholderFragment"  >  

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fees Due Page"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #108: Error inflating class null
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                                            at com.example.arjun.scol.Fees.Fees1due.onCreateView(Fees1due.java:28)
>                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
>                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
>                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
>                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
>                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1638)
>                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
>                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
>                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1240)
>                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1088)
>                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15562)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
>                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:700)
>                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
>                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1364)
>                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:765)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15562)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
>                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15562)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
>                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
>                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
>                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15562)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
>                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15562)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
>                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
>                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
>                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15562)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
>                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15562)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2006)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1245)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1420)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1138)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4655)
>                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
>                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
>                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
>                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:

Kindly help..pls..

Comment: post the `fees1due` layout code

Comment: Show your xml filr.

Comment: @Drv  posted the xml...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 posted xml..